# Creating an iso file in Linux

Tags: linux, iso, dd, cp

I have created iso files by using two commands:

- dd if=/dev/cdrom of=*filename*
- cp /dev/cdrom *filename*

What's the difference between the two, both have worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For copying CDs then both are fine although I generally expliciatlly set the block size by doing

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=cdrom.iso bs=512
```

For other block devices then cp might not work if the block size on the device is unexpected.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)

> Note that an attempt to copy the entire disk image using cp may omit the final block if it is an unexpected length; dd will always complete the copy if possible.

Comment: You should add the "conv=sync,notrunc" parameter from the wikipedia page. Else your quote is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, my first command wasn't from wikipedia only the block quote. Updated text to reflect this.

Comment: FYI, block size on CD-ROM is actually 2048 octects

Comment: Seems you learn something every day.

I've always used 512 but it appears this dates back to SCSI days when most drivers were 512 or 2048.

I'll use 2048 from now on. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There's effectively no difference, some very minor caveats aside.

Both `dd` and `cp` will read all blocks from the input source (the `/dev/cdrom` block device) and copy the whole CD-ROM to the destination file.

`dd` is however the "right" way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the dd command allows for a "byte-exact" copy of the specified input. If the dd command is used on a disk rather than the cdrom, it will be able to copy previously deleted files which cannot be seen by the cp command from the filesystem interface. But since you are using /dev/cdrom as the input (which doesn't have the same structure as a disk), there are no previously deleted files on the interface, so the commands *should* work exactly the same.

for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)

Comment: no, i mean cp /dev/cdrom as an input.

Comment: incorrect answer - /dev/cdrom is a block device, not a filesystem directory.  /dev/cdrom *is* the disk structure.

Comment: You clearly can't read

Comment: ok, I've slightly misunderstood your answer, but I *still* can't figure out what you meant in the first half of the last sentence.  The comparison with a disk and mention of deleted files is very confusing.

Comment: From the wikipedia article "Using cp would not be possible because data from deleted files still physically present on a disk are not visible through the file system interface." And i said this isn't applicable to a cdrom because it does not retain information like a disk.

Comment: Hence why both commands work the same