# How to mount an ISO file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, iso, loopback

I have just created ISO using these instructions:

> [Creating an iso file in Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/5689)

How can I mount this iso image that was created?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following command helped:

> mount -o loop -t iso9660 file.iso /mnt/test

Found here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/857/mount-an-iso-file-in-linux/

Comment: what if the image isn't iso9660 e.g. UDF?

Comment: @jmtd - I tried my movie (copied using Brasero) with both forcing `-t iso9660` and `-t udf`. Both do mount but iso9660 causes the filenames to be lowercased (e.g., `video_ts.ifo`). Normally these files should be in caps. When using `udf`, indeed they are in caps. Both types worked fine when I used `vlc /mnt/test`. In fact I can just do `vlc file.iso` without the need of a loopback device. I used /usr/bin/file file.iso` which reported UDF 1.5 format.

Answer (score 29):

Linux has a loopback device which lets you mount files that contain a filesystem on them. This will work for images of partitions (i.e. an ext3 backup image) but also works for cdrom images as well.

This command allows you to mount an iso image. In order of this to work, `/mnt/disk` must already exist:

```
mount -o loop disk.iso /mnt/disk
```

The `-o` switch is for mount options. The `loop` option tells the mount command to find the first `/dev/loopX` device and use it.

Comment: Better answer than those also specifying -t iso9660. This is better auto-detected, as the image could be UDF or another format.

Comment: +1 For not only the actual command, but for the additional details as well.

Comment: Note that (as for other solutions on this page) you need to be root to do this.

Comment: Agree with @jmtd to consider leaving out `-t iso9660`. Auto-detect worked for me. I also suggest `/usr/bin/file disk.iso` to determine format (iso9660 vs. udf).

Answer (score 2):

like that:

`mount -o loop -t iso9660 whatever.iso /mnt`

Comment: As per Antonio's answer, what if the image is not iso9660?

Comment: The iso9660 option seems to detect most variations of optical disk images including DVD, not just CD or CD-*.

Answer (score 1):

```
You will probably need to create folder first like this..

$ mkdir/mnt/cd/

$ mount -o loop -t iso9660 whatever.iso /mnt/cd/

and think this work 

$ umount /mnt/cd/
$ mount -o loop -t iso9660 whatever.iso /mnt

if you need to mount hardrive , usb .. osv..
find out name and place..

$ fdisk -l
Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048  1050623  1048576  512M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2   1050624 18020351 16969728  8,1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  18020352 30365695 12345344  5,9G Linux swap

$ mkdir /mnt/sdb2
$ mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/sdb2
$ cd /mnt/sdb2/
```

Comment: This question already received a more generally usable version this answer (in fact several copies of the same answer) 5 years ago. I don't really see this adding anything new. May I recommend trawling the Unanswered tab? There's gobs in there.

Comment: was only trying to be helpful... will not be repeated
... Peace.. over and out.

Comment: Trying to be helpful is awesome! Reposting already existing answers ends up being the forum equivalent of "Me too!" which ends up being not helpful. That's why I was pointing at the Unanswered list. Lots of stuff in there deserves answers, they just haven't found them yet.

Comment: Answers by new users on really old questions end up in the review queues because really old questions are often targets for spam, so your answer got a lot of extra scrutiny.  I'd recommend trying again on a newer question that doesn't already have a lot of answers.

Answer (score -1):

You want to do a loop mount.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html

Comment: Please put the instruction in your answers.  What if nixCraft went offline?

Answer (score -2):

Follow the simple steps shown below :
Just Create a Directory :

```
mkdir /mnt/isomount
```

Now mount the iso image using below command.

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /app/file.iso /mnt/isomount/
```

Where :

**-t** :   Used to Indicate the File System Type.

**iso9660** :   It is an Standard by International Organisation Standardiztion (ISO) for Medias (CD/DVD).

**-o** :   Options are specified with a -o flag followed by a  comma  separated  string of options.

**loop** :   It is a pseudo-device or a fake device that is allow you to mount a file and makes a file accessible as a block device. Loop devices are often used for ISO images. We can check the mounted devices by below command.